# How to get how many chapters read by user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having three tables `bible_chapters`, `bible_reading_portions`, `user_bible_trackings`, 1 chapter may have multiple bible portions and we are tracking portions in user_bible_trackings table. Below is my schema:-

```
bible_chapters
id    chapter_name 
1       Chpt1
2       Chpt2
3       Chpt3

bible_reading_portions
id      bible_chapter_id     portion_name
1          1                    Chp1P1
2          2                    Chp2P1
3          2                    Chp2P2
4          2                    Chp2P3
5          3                    Chp3P1

user_bible_trackings
 id    bible_reading_portion_id       user_id
 1         1                            1
 2         2                            1
 3         3                            1
 4         4                            1
 5         1                            1
 6         2                            1
 7         3                            1
 8         4                            1 
 9         1                            1
 10        2                            1
```

So you see that above `user_bible_trackings` table `user_id` 1  have read `Chpt1` 3 times and `Chpt2` 2 times and user again started the chapter2 3rd time but its not complete yet beacuse chapt2 belongs to 3 portions,.... for the 3rd time user not read all the portions. So my expected output be like:-

```
 user_id    total_chapteres_read
  1               5  // i.e means user read chpt1 3 times and chpt2 2 times so count will be 3+2=5
```

Can anyone help me how can i acheieve the same.

@Akina  PLease check i have added the schema queries below:-

```
CREATE TABLE `bible_chapters` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`chapter_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `bible_chapters` (`id`, `chapter_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Chp1'),
(2, 'Chp2'),
(3, 'Chp3');

---------------------
CREATE TABLE `bible_reading_portions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bible_chapter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `portion_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `bible_reading_portions` (`id`, `bible_chapter_id`, `portion_name`) 
 VALUES
 (1, 1, 'Chp1p1'),
 (2, 2, 'Chp2p2'),
 (3, 2, 'Chp2p2'),
 (4, 2, 'Chp2p3');

 -----------  
  CREATE TABLE `user_bible_trackings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `bible_reading_portion_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

    INSERT INTO `user_bible_trackings` (`id`, `bible_reading_portion_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
     (1, 1, 1),
     (2, 2, 1),
     (3, 3, 1),
     (4, 4, 1),
     (5, 1, 1),
     (6, 2, 1),
     (7, 3, 1),
     (8, 4, 1),
     (9, 1, 1),
     (10, 2, 1);
```

Comment: @Akina Please check my updated question

Comment: @Akina have you checked my schema is it fine?

Comment: The schema you created looks to be fine.. Hav you find the solution for above output?

Comment: Does the order of reading makes sense? if the user have read chapter 2 portions in another order (for example, firstly 2, then 1, then 3), does this must be count as complete chapter reading?

Comment: they can read any portion any way like chapter2 portion  they can read no. 3 portion first and 2 after and no. 4 later. so order can be any

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236895/discussion-between-kunal-and-akina).

Comment: @Akina if user read chapter 2 like 3,4,2 portions it  will be count as 1 .... if these values exists multiple times like 3,4,2 ..... 2,3,4, ..... 4,2,3  so we will count as 3 times same chapter read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT ubt.user_id, 
           bc.id bc_id, bc.chapter_name, 
           brp.id brp_id, brp.portion_name, 
           COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM bible_chapters bc
    JOIN bible_reading_portions brp ON bc.id = brp.bible_chapter_id
    JOIN user_bible_trackings ubt ON brp.id = ubt.bible_reading_portion_id
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT user_id, bc_id, 
           COUNT(brp_id) portions_count, 
           MIN(cnt) complete_readings
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT user_id, SUM(complete_readings) total_readings
FROM cte2
GROUP BY 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b4c3c7754c8bd33e0398679c7f97617) with some comments.

The solution does not check does all portions of a chapter were read. For to take this into account you must compare `portions_count` (added but not used) with the same value for a chapter (obtained in separate CTE).

Comment: how to add where user_id = 1 and what is GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5 ??

Comment: @kunal *how to add where user_id = 1* Add this to CTE1 query. *what is GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5* Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses using column names, column aliases, or column positions. I use the latter option.

Comment: i have added one more portion to chapter id 2 and its not in trackings table and its still showing count 5 it must show as 3

Comment: I have told about this. Do it by yourself, this is easy.

Comment: i am trying but not able to do . Can you please help ?

Comment: i tried the same portions_count is stil coming 3 instead of 4